# Grouping data with sequence counters in python

Tags: python, pandas

Opening a new request, since the previous one couldn't get answered completely.Please merge these if possible.

## [Sequence counters for group based data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887886/sequence-counters-for-group-based-data-in-python)

I want to group the repeating sequences in `column A`. `Column A` can have any number and not restricted to *0, 1, 2*. So basically, all rows between two 0's needs to be assigned a value in B which increments with every such group. Here is sample data. A and B are fields on a `Dataframe` and there are others too.

```
A   B
0   1
1   1
2   1
0   2
1   2
2   2
0   3
1   3
2   3
1   3
2   3
0   4
1   4
2   4
2   4
```

Comment: df.A.eq(0).cumsum()?

Comment: @Wen-Ben - That truly worked!! Thanks!